# Property [id] does not exist laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am creating A notifcation for user that created a new post on my site and the user will be awarded point after creating a post, so when a user create a post and get a point send notification but im getting this error

Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

please how can I resolve this issue kindly assist me

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Gamify\Points\PostCreated;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Tag;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\PointAdd;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class PostCreate extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $post;
    public $user;
    public $body;
    public $slug;
    public $photo;
    public $title;
    public $category = 1;
    public $points = 10;
    public $energy = 1;

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->points++;
    }

    protected $rules = [
        'category' => 'required|integer|exists:categories,id',
        'title' => 'required|min:4',
        'body' => 'required|min:4',
    ];

    public function createPost()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $this->validate();
            $random =  str_pad(mt_rand(1,999999),6,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $post = Post::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'title' => $this->title,
                'category_id' => $this->category,
                'body' => $this->body,
                'post_number' => $random,
                'slug' => Str::slug($this->title),
            ]);
                $user = auth()->user();
                $points = $user->givePoint(new PostCreated($post));
                $user->notify(new PointAdd($points));

                $image = $this->photo->storeAs('posts', str::random(30));
                $post->image = $image;
                $post->save();
                session()->flash("message", "Featured image successfully uploaded");

                preg_match_all('/(?<=#)(\w+)/mi', $this->body, $matchedTags, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
                foreach ($matchedTags as $matchedTag) {
                    if (!$tag = Tag::where('name', $matchedTag[0])->first()) {
                        $tag = tag::create(['name' => $matchedTag[0]]);
                    }
                    $post->tags()->attach($tag->id);
                    $tag->addEnergy(1);
                }

                preg_match_all('/(?<=@)(\w+)/mi', $this->body, $matchedMentions, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
                foreach ($matchedMentions as $matchedMention) {
                    optional(User::where('username', $matchedMention[0])->first(), function ($user) {
                        // $user->notify(new MentionsNotify($user));
                    });
                 }


            // $users = auth()->user();
            // $users->increment('points', 10);

            session()->flash('success_message', 'Post was added successfully!');

            $this->reset();

            return redirect()->route('post.index');
        }

        abort(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

My notification components

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class PointAdd extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail', 'database'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => $this->user->id,
            'user_name' => $this->user->name,
            'user_avatar' => $this->user->avatar,
            'user_points' => $this->user->reputation,
            'post_id' => $this->user->post->id,

        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `givePoint` method return? You are passing that method to the PointAdd notification class but accepting a User class. Which is probably empty and is causing that error.

Comment: `$this->user->post->id,` seems to imply a user can only ever have a single post and you always assume it exists. Maybe pass the actual Post instance you are interested in the notification constructor so you can use the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `$points` object to notification which expects a `User` model. If your `givePoint()` method (which you didn't share) does not return a `User` model then that's the problem.

You can add in your notification, under `use Queueable;` the `protected User $user;` definition and check if notification throws an error.